# Resolving Homebrew warnings without causing adverse effects

Tags: mysql, node.js, git, homebrew, macos-sierra

I am having issues installing mysql with Homebrew and have ran `brew doctor` to try and get to the bottom of it.

The advice given is always to resolve the warnings/errors presented by Homebrew, however I do not want to cause adverse side-effects on my system by doing so.

As I understand it, the node errors are likely caused by installing Node manually and not with Homebrew. I'm not sure what the git unlinked keg is about.

What is the safest way to resolve these errors?

```
CRMPiccos-MacBook:~ crmpicco$ brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected header files:
  /usr/local/include/node/node_internals.h
  /usr/local/include/node/smalloc.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8stdint.h

Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
  git
```

Answer (score 0):

> As I understand it, the node errors are likely caused by installing Node manually and not with Homebrew.

I don’t know where these files come from but if you’re afraid of removing them you could just move them somewhere then move them back if they’re needed.

> I'm not sure what the git unlinked keg is about.

`git` is installed but not symlinked into standard locations like `/usr/local/bin` and friends. Programs that depend on that specific `git` installation thus can’t find it. You should either run `brew link git` or `brew rm git` if you don’t have any formula that depend on it.

Comment: Could this affect my default git installation in any way though? Or is it safe to do so? What about `grunt`?

Comment: @crmpicco It won’t affect your default git installation since it’s not linked. (edit: also note all of this can be rollbacked: `brew link git` -> `brew unlink git`; `brew rm git` -> `brew install git`).